# Why does my try/catch block keep looping?

Tags: java, try-catch

When I run this, the code skips over `input.nextInt();` and goes in circles:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Link user to programs (ToC)
    int loop = 1;

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please choose a number: ");
            System.out.println("0. Exit");
            System.out.println("1. Calculator");
            int numChoice = input.nextInt();
            if (numChoice == 0) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (numChoice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Going to Calculator...");
                new Calculator();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not a valid choice.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please input a number!");
        }
    } while (loop == 1);
}
```

It seems to be skipping `int numChoice` for whatever reason. Also, please don't be too technical. I just code for my leisure.

Comment: Why do you use `loop` in `while (loop == 1)` if you are not going to update this variable inside your loop? Wouldn't `while(true)` be simpler since you are already using `System.exit(0);` to stop your application?

Comment: Good point. I will change that, but I still don't know how to make it stop looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop goes in circles for two reasons:

- You try for `nextInt`, but you do not clear out the input buffer on failure, and
- Even if you did clear input in the `catch`, your loop would still go on, because there are no assignments of the `loop` variable which is supposed to stop your loop.

Comment: @Alexander call input.next(); inside the catch block.

Comment: catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please input a number!");
                numChoice = input.nextInt();
            }
This returns error. Also, NetBeans says the code doesn't reach there.

Comment: No. I ran out of ideas.

Comment: @Alexander This is strange, because your code works with the modification from your comment. See [this link for a demo](http://ideone.com/ilRt2r).

Comment: Thank you. It works! But how does input.next() relate to int? And how does it work without a variable in front?

Comment: @Alexander `input.next()` takes the next string, not necessarily representing an `int`. That's the difference: `nextInt` will not take anything unless the user typed a sequence of digits, while `next` will take whatever is there. The reason there's no variable to assign it to is that I do not need to use the string returned by `next()` - I know it's not an `int`, so I want to discard it right away.